# How to obtain Sandbox Test Business-Pro Account transaction log using Paypal APIs?

Tags: paypal

I need to get a list of all transfers/payments that are being made towards a Paypal Business-Pro Account, during a certain period. I have to get it programmatically via Paypal APIs within a Microsoft .Net based application.

Comment: Welcome. Please see these notes on how to ask a question which will get a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for programmatic solution via API then best way is to use "[TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/)" API and with this you can pull out all the transactions with in a date range .

And if you want more details for each individual transaction then you can use this API in conjunction with "[GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)" API.